# Forward variadic template args to several class members

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Is the following safe? Won't the `std::string` be `move`d after the first class member is initialised? It prints out ok but I'm not sure.

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:

    template <typename... Args>
    Test(Args&&... args)
    :  m_one(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)),
       m_two(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))    // <- Here
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_one;
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_two;
};


class C
{ 
public:

    C(int a, int b, const std::string& c)
    :  m_a(a),
       m_b(b),
       m_c(c)
    {
        std::cout << "ctor a=" << m_a << ", b=" << m_b << ", c=" << m_c << "\n";
    }

    int m_a;
    int m_b;
    std::string m_c;
};


int main()
{
     Test<C> t(1, 2, "3");
}
```

I guess it's ok since the third ctor param of `C` is `const std::string&`, but how do I prevent perfect forwarding in a class that takes an r-value ref, e.g. `C(int, int, std::string&&)` as then `m_two` will not receive the same ctor args as `m_one`?

Changing the ctor of Test to

```
   template <typename... Args>
   Test(Args&... args)
```

doesn't compile. Nor does removing the `std::forward<Args>(args)...` from `m_one` and `m_two` ctors.

Comment: Maybe it would be better not to use `std::forward` when initializing `m_one`.

Comment: That doesn't compile:  main.cpp:31: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_string<char>' lvalue to 'std::string&& {aka std::basic_string<char>&&}'

Comment: @James: You must be doing something wrong. What Vaughn means is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fdc7ca0f433a18a). The rule of thumb is: When perfect-forwarding the same argument multiple times, ***don't***. Simply pass it on without perfect-forwarding, and let targets make a copy if they want to. If you want to forward, only do it on the last occasion (in this case in the initialization of `m_two`).

Comment: @Xeo, yes you are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to want to use something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:

    template <typename... Args>
    Test(Args&&... args)
    :  m_one(new T(args...)),                    // avoid moving the first time
       m_two(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) // but allowing moving the last time
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_one;
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_two;
};


class C
{
public:

    C(int a, int b, std::string c) // rule of thumb -- if you are going to copy an argument
                                   // anyway, pass it by value.
    :  m_a(a),
       m_b(b),
       m_c(std::move(c)) // you can safely move here since it is the last use. 
    {
        std::cout << "ctor a=" << m_a << ", b=" << m_b << ", c=" << m_c << "\n";
    }

    int m_a;
    int m_b;
    std::string m_c;
};
```

For `m_one`, the arguments use lvalue references, so no moving will take place.  For `m_two`, the `std::forward` will use rvalue references as appropriate.  Taking the `std::string` argument to `C` by value and using `std::move` makes it work properly for either case.  If you pass an lvalue reference, then the argument will be copy-constructed, but if you pass an rvalue reference, the argument will be move-constructed.  In either case, you can move the argument into your `m_c` member for efficiency.